# Finding duplicate numbers

Tags: java

I have written this code which finds duplicate numbers and the occurrence of a particular number in an array. I have used a `HashMap`, but I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do the same, or whether I should be using another method.

```
import java.util.*;
class test7
{
    public static void main(String ...a)
    {
        int []arr={10,20,10,2,11,10,32,15,15,10,10};
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> num=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        for(int t: arr) 
        {       
            Integer tmp_int=new Integer(t);
            if(num.containsKey(tmp_int))
            {   
                Integer i_ob=num.get(tmp_int);
                num.put(tmp_int,new Integer(i_ob.intValue()+1));
            }
            else
            {
                num.put(tmp_int,new Integer(1));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
{32=1, 2=1, 20=1, 10=5, 11=1, 15=2}
```

Comment: Regardless of the fact that explicit boxing is unnecessary here, it's better to use [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) than the constructor `Integer(int)` (see the documentation of that method, to which I linked the method name, for an explanation why).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your code. The logic is same as you have done. You do not need to create those `Integer`. Read about [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). If the input array is large, you will see performance hit for creating Integer. Note that Integer is a class, and not a primitive type in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                                                                                            
    int[] arr={10,20,10,2,11,10,32,15,15,10,10};                                                                                                                                      
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();                                                                                                                 

    for(int element : arr)                                                                                                                                                            
      {                                                                                                                                                                               
        if(result.containsKey(element))                                                                                                                                               
          {                                                                                                                                                                           
            result.put(element, result.get(element) + 1);                                                                                                                             
          }                                                                                                                                                                           
        else                                                                                                                                                                          
          {                                                                                                                                                                           
            result.put(element, 1);                                                                                                                                                   
          }                                                                                                                                                                           
      }                                                                                                                                                                               
    System.out.println(result);                                                                                                                                                       
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32516817/5934924) you could use [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) to find duplicate numbers in java 8:

```
numbers.stream()
    .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(numbers, i) >1)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```